# Scrollbar on Canvas with frame inside

Tags: canvas, tkinter, scrollbar, frame

I have a scroll bar on a canvas. In the canvas I have a frame attached. The scrollbar moves the contents of the frame BUT the scrolling action is not confined to the size of the frame it scrolls indefinitely up and down. Also the thumb on the scrollbar is the entire size of the scrollbar. This issue I'm guessing will be corrected once I can figure out how to tell the scrollbar what the scroll region is.

```
outside_frame = Frame(self.master)
outside_frame.pack(fill=X, padx=20)

vscrollbar = Scrollbar(outside_frame, width = 20,orient=VERTICAL)
vscrollbar.pack(fill=Y,side=RIGHT, expand=FALSE)

canvas_files = Canvas(outside_frame,bd=0,yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)
canvas_files.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)
vscrollbar.config(command=canvas_files.yview)

canvas_files.xview_moveto(0)
canvas_files.yview_moveto(0)      


frame_files=Frame(canvas_files)
frame_files_id = canvas_files.create_window(0 ,0, window=frame_files, anchor=NW)
```

Comment: There are many examples of this on stackoverflow. Were none of them helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `scrollregion` option to your canvas, for example:

```
scrollregion=(0,0,500,500)
```

Comment: The issue here is that the frame size isn't fixed. It is a custom file picker that varies in height depending on the number of files. I tried canvas_files.configure(scrollregion = canvas_files.bbox("all")) which limited the scroll region but not to the correct value.

Comment: I added scrollregion=(0,0,300,1000) which mostly fixed my problem but I need to make the height dynamic to the height of the frame which will change.

Comment: If you do `scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")` once the frame is visible, the scrollregion will exactly match the size of the objects in the canvas. this is typically done by binding to the `<Configure>` event on the internal frame, since that even will fire whenever the frame changes size.

Comment: @MFerrero199 I cannot see how you are adding new files onto the canvas in your current code, but if it's a function, then add `.bbox("all")` at the end of your function body. This will get you there for sure I believe!

Answer (score 0):

So, the only think I could get working was to add 100 to the scroll region for each row of files created. This solved the problem and scroll bar working as intended. bbox('all') did not work regardless of where I put it. I'm sure that would be the "correct" way to resolve the issue but I am moving on. Thanks to all for your help in pointing me in the right direction.